# Can I call Thread.currentThread().interrupt() when I am iterating over map of future?

Tags: java, multithreading

It is safe to call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` when I am iterating future over map like this ?

```
    for (Map.Entry<Key, List<Future<Value>>> entry : valuesByKey.entrySet()) {
        List<Future<Value>> values = entry.getValue();
        Key key = entry.getKey();

        try {
            for (Future<Value> future : results) {
                try {
                    Value value = future.get();
                    editKey(key, value);
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    LOG.error(e);
                } catch (CancellationException e) {
                    LOG.error(e);
                }
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            for (Future<?> future : values) {
                if (!future.isDone())
                    // cancel all job threads that haven't been run yet, let existing complete
                    future.cancel(false);
            }
            // Restore the interrupted status on the job thread
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes you can ................

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly safe for a thread to set its own interrupt flag, but you're doing that without breaking out of the loop.  I'm *guessing* that what will happen next is, the loop will visit every remaining entry in the map, and it will call `editKey(k,v)` for all of the futures that have completed, but it will not wait for any of the futures that have not completed.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: yes it is. I need to edit key according to result of future. If there is some error to get result I dont need to edit it.